# C++. How to change each element in vector?

Tags: c++

I have a vector from those elements (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
I have to change each element using only standard algorithms. For example, how to sum each element with num 5? To have (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
Thanks alot for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply something like this:

```
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
transform(begin(v), end(v), begin(v), [](int e) -> int {return e + 5;});
```